# Group GUI checkboxes (AbstrackButtons) together and set properties for all of them

Tags: qt, user-interface

I have several radio buttons and checkboxes that all have to be grayed out.

Is their a way to group them and then set the attributes for all of them on the same place?

**Example**

The QRadioButton and QCheckBox are added to the groupBox (QGroupBox) through the gui designer.
Then do something like this to set all the attributes:

```
ui->groupBox->setChilrenCheckable()
```

Comment: Did you try disabling your groupbox? `ui->groupBox->setEnabled(false);`

Comment: That works great. Please supply it as an answer. I will wait some time before accepting it to see if a more generic solution exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the groupbox:

```
ui->groupBox->setEnabled(false);
```